# How to create a "Status" based on field values?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

OK, this one might be simple and I am just not thinking it out right, or it is complex and will require code, please help.

I need a way in a custom list to set a Item Status Value based on if one of three fields contains a value. Example:

```
Field:RenewalDate value = Something 
      then Status = Active
Field:LapseDate value = something 
      and Field:RenewalDate = NULL 
      then Status = LAPSED 
Field:CancelledDate value = Something 
      and Field:RenewalDate value = NULL 
      and Field:LapseDate value = NULL 
      then Status = Cancelled
```

I then want to be able to sort a view based on the Status.

Comment: Considered a Workflow?

Comment: Or a Calculated field? (I can't remember if this will sort, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Calculated Column Formula *like (of the top of my head*)

```
=IF( NOT( ISBLANK( [RenewelDate] )) 
     , "Active" , 
     IF( AND( NOT( ISBLANK( [LapseDate] )) 
              ,ISBLANK([RenewelDate]) 
            ) 
         , "LAPSED" 
         IF( AND( NOT( ISBLANK( [CancelledDate] )) 
                  ,ISBLANK([RenewelDate]) 
                  ,ISBLANK([LapseDate]) 
                ) 
             , "Cancelled" 
             , "" 
           ) 
       ) 
   )
```

It is easier to built your Formulas in Excel using *named ranges*, SharePoint is a pain to develop by trial

Calculated Formula results sort like any other field.

Comment: Danny - I was able to get this much to work correctly:
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(RenewalDate)),"Active",
IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(LapseDate)),ISBLANK(RenewalDate)),"LAPSED"

When I add the last part it errors out.

Comment: Make it work in Excel first and break it apart if you have problems... Hint: I spot missing **)** in 2 IF lines

Comment: Once again Danny you are a Rock Star, thank you for the advice and direction!